# Scraping Script Tags with VBA

Tags: javascript, vba, excel

Is there a way to extract just the values of pageListIs: & pageItemId using VBA?

I tried to use XPATH to get the value but it returns the whole script 

XPATH = //script[contains(text(), "pageItemId:")]/text()

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
var _fV4UI=true;var _spPageContextInfo = webLanguage: 1033, currentLanguage: 1033, webUIVersion:4,pageListId:"{8faf05f2-b852-44b4-8a46-c7ee47b76e0a}",pageItemId:375,userId:24161, alertsEnabled:false, siteServerRelativeUrl: "\u002fsites\u002fcontent", allowSilverlightPrompt:'True'};//]]>
</script>
```

Is there a way to just extract just the 2 values with VBA? or any other suggestions?

Comment: Yes, once you have the xpath text then instr function can be used to get any text.

Comment: So it it returning the HTML you are showing?

Comment: Santosh, i'll explore more on that. Thanks.

QHarr, yes, it's returning the HTML inside the <script> tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Split function on the string retrieved e.g.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub GetInfo()
    Dim s As String
    s = [A1] '<== I am reading the HTML you showed in from a cell. You would use the HTML retrieve via XPath

    Debug.Print "pageItemId=" & Split(Split(s, "pageItemId:")(1), ",")(0)
    Debug.Print "userId=" & Split(Split(s, "userId:")(1), ",")(0)
End Sub
```

---

**Result:**

[image: Retrieved]

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks a lot. I believe with slight modification, i can achieve the result i want.

Comment: Sorry, i'm new to stackoverflow, I went on to press "This Answer is Useful" instead of marking as answer. Anyway, this is the answer i was expecting.

Comment: Thanks Again QHarr. Mind looking into this if you're free?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51316826/excel-vba-removing-part-of-a-url-after-certain-text