# Excel VBA - removing part of a URL after certain text

Tags: vba, excel

How to remove part of URL's after certain text?

Let's say i have the following URL's in cell A1 to A4:

https://stackoverflow.com/testing/testing1/en/unwantedTest.aspx
https://stackoverflow.com/extra/testing/testing2/en/unwantedTest.aspx
https://stackoverflow.com/testing/testing3/ko/unwantedTest.aspx
https://stackoverflow.com/extra2/testing/testing4/testing5/ko/unwantedTest.aspx

The expected result i want is:
https://stackoverflow.com/testing/testing1/en/
https://stackoverflow.com/extra/testing/testing2/en/
https://stackoverflow.com/testing/testing3/ko/
https://stackoverflow.com/extra2/testing/testing4/testing5/ko/
Anything after **en/** or **ko/** should be removed.

So can someone explain or show me how to do this please.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you want this with VBA or a formula? Pretty easy with the `LEFT` and `FIND` formulas - and many VBA examples on SO as well.

Comment: I prefer VBA but formula would do as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with `Left`, `InStr`, and `Len`. `Instr` returns the position of the first occurrence of the string. You add the length of the string sought (e.g. "en/") and then subtract 1 to get the appropriate number of characters to return from the hyperlink, starting from the left.

Using the example links you provided, in cells A1 to A4 on Sheet1...

```
Sub TruncateHyperlinks()
    Dim l As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    For l = 1 To 4
        Set rng = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & l)

        If InStr(rng.Value, "en/") Then
            Debug.Print Left(rng.Value, InStr(rng.Value, "en/") + Len("en/") - 1)
        ElseIf InStr(rng.Value, "ko/") Then
            Debug.Print Left(rng.Value, InStr(rng.Value, "ko/") + Len("ko/") - 1)
        End If
    Next l
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: This is great. It works like what i wanted it to. I'll modify it to suit my wabts. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

use this function
B2 = truntext(A1)

```html
Function truntext(textstring as string)
  dim ar
  ar = split(textstring, "/")
  truntext = left(textstring , len(textstring ) - len(ar(ubound(ar))))
end function
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're just wanting anything after ko or en and don't want to write VB, you can just use the MID function.

```
=MID(A1,1,IFERROR(FIND("/ko",A1),FIND("/en",A1))+3)
```